# How to downgrade CUDA to 7.0 version on win 7 for cudafy.net?

Tags: windows-7-x64

I would like to use cudafy.net
But it is no longer supported and requires cuda 7.0

I have windows 7 and I cannot find cuda 7.0 for windows 7.

Yesterday I spent whole day without success. 
If somebody could help me with cudafy.net I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find it in the legacy download page of CUDA, pointing [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-70) for CUDA 7.0. It reads it supports Windows 7.

Comment: I tried to install this on windows 7 but I get following error: https://s24.postimg.org/534zesy39/image.png

Comment: @Petras, it just means that the driver could not find your graphics card. You need to install the dirver that recognizes your card either after installation, or before installation. If before, uncheck the driver installation checkbox from the install instruction.

Comment: cuda 8 could recognize my driver and visual studio 2015, but cuda 7 do not. Where to download specific driver for cuda 7 and which version of visual studio I should run? Thank you.